# VBA: Create a table from the suggested range

Tags: excel, listobject

Every day I get a excel sheet with some data in a cell range. I recorded a macro which turns a defined range into a proper table and then processes the data:

```
Sub Macro1
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$CP$8221"), , xlYes).Name _
        = "myTable"
    ' Further processing follows
End Sub
```

My problem is that the Range varies. It has a different number of lines and columns every day. What command should I use instead to define a table of the range suggested by default? By *default* I mean the range you get as a suggestion when you place the cursor anywhere inside the data range and hit Ctrl+T to create a table.

Comment: `Range("A1").CurrentRegion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) wrote a sufficient answer in his comment: `Range("A1").CurrentRegion`